# Move an object after grabbing in orbital motion to Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive, vrtk

I am trying to make a day night cycle in which **Sun/Moon in front of the Camera and its grab able but only moves in orbit around the steam VR camera rig**.

I am able to make that object grab able using VRTK (its a toolkit for vive) but how  can i move it like as if it is orbiting the camera rig and dose not deviate from orbital path.
I have no idea where to start it, 
honestly i have tried nothing because i do not know where to start it or how can i be able to do this 
help needed... 
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options if you search online, [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Hermite_Spline_Controller) is an example that could help you out.

And [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Au3d.as+spline&oq=site%3Au3d.as+spline&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.479j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are some more ideas.

Referenced from [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/447870/moving-a-gameobject-along-a-custom-curved-spline.html).

Comment: i don't want to animate it of some sort,
i want to move it in to a circular motion with my controller as if it moves in (HTC vive) controllers movement direction

Comment: Nobody said you have to animate anything, if you follow my first link you can see that you can make a specific trajectory with splines, next you just have to move your sun/moon only on that slpine

Comment: doesn't matter how you move it, could be with a controller, or mouse, or script, or animation, or force